# Xamarin MSAL WebView Customization

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL library in Xamarin to integrate Azure B2C. I am using WebView for interactive login.
Everything works fine.

```
var authResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.B2CConstants.Scopes)
                              .WithAccount(GetAccountByUsername(accounts, username))
                              .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                              .ExecuteAsync();
```

[Sign-in Page in WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/media/msal-net-web-browsers/embedded-webview.png)

The sing-in page is having "Sign In" bar with black background. Please refer above link. It is very different from our app theming. Can we customize the background or remove that bar title? Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Based on my research, it cannot be achieved, this page is generated by the `msal` plugin.

Comment: Okay thanks for you comment